# One-to-one self-referential relationship using an association table in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationships

So I have a parent child relationship between `Topic` models with the relationship represented by this class:

```
class ParentChildRelation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent_child_relation'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_topic_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topic.id'), nullable=False)
    parent_topic_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topic.id'), nullable=False)
```

And the topics defined as such:

```
class Topic(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'topic'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    parent = db.relationship(
        'Topic',
        secondary='parent_child_relation',
        primaryjoin='Topic.id == ParentChildRelation.child_topic_id',
        secondaryjoin='Topic.id == ParentChildRelation.parent_topic_id'
    )
```

I'd like to have `parent` be a **one-to-one** relationship for now (I might change it later on), but it comes back as an `InstrumentedList`.  Is there a simple way of stating that `parent` should be a one-to-one relationship such that it links directly to a `Topic` model instead of being an `InstrumentedList`?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had previously found the correct answer, but I must have had a typo :/.  Adding [uselist](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.uselist)=False did the trick.

```
parent = db.relationship(
    'Topic',
    secondary='parent_child_relation',
    primaryjoin='Topic.id == ParentChildRelation.child_topic_id',
    secondaryjoin='Topic.id == ParentChildRelation.parent_topic_id',
    uselist=False
)
```